# How to scale down the joint axes in RVIZ?

Tags: ros, rviz

I am trying to scale down the joint axes of my robot in RVIZ, there do not appear to be a scale option, is this correct?

To clarify, it is importent that it is the actual joint axes and not the link axes!

I have tried:

- Adding TF - only seems to be able to visualise link axes.
- Going to RobotModel and changeing "Links" to "Joints" in the "Link Tree Style" dropdown - the axes are way too big and there do not appear to be a scale option.